# Use JS variable value as iframe src

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, append

I have variable,x, that holds a value (the URL). I want to my iframe src to hold the value of x.

```
<script type=”javascript/text”>
var x="http://stackoverflow.com/";
  }
</script>

<iframe src="URL"></iframe>
```

How do I do this?

The JS code and the HTML are in the same document.

Thank you.

Comment: You can set the [`src` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement#Properties) within the `<script>` given you have a reference to the element -- `aParticularIframe.src = x;`.

Comment: This is the code I am using - http://jsfiddle.net/Hu6qq/  The URLs don't open.

Comment: `google.com` and `stackoverflow.com` have specified [not to be loaded into an unknown frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options), and your browser is obliging them. I assume `youtube.com` is doing the same, but can't verify at the moment. If you check your browser's console, you may see an error like: *`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`*